# PluginTransformationException: Unable to add files to plugin jar

Tags: jira, jira-plugin

We are having a problem building plugin project. We were able to run project without error. When we change the computer for building we get this error.

```
Jira Version:6.2.1
```

Console output:

```
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 2016-05-26 12:06:42,466 localhost-startStop-1 ERROR[plugin.osgi.factory.OsgiPluginFactory] Unable to load plugin: C:\Atlassian\jira\com.lbs.jira.plugins\target\jira\home\plugins\installed-plugins\logo-jira-plugin-4.0.8.jar
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]com.atlassian.plugin.osgi.factory.transform.PluginTransformationException: Unable to add files to plugin jar
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] at com.atlassian.plugin.osgi.factory.transform.DefaultPluginTransformer.transform(DefaultPluginTransformer.java:170)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] at com.atlassian.plugin.osgi.factory.OsgiPluginFactory.createOsgiPluginJar(OsgiPluginFactory.java:301)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] at com.atlassian.plugin.osgi.factory.OsgiPluginFactory.create(OsgiPluginFactory.java:224)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] at com.atlassian.jira.plugin.MasterPluginFactory.create(MasterPluginFactory.java:80)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] at com.atlassian.plugin.loaders.ScanningPluginLoader.deployPluginFromUnit(ScanningPluginLoader.java:155)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] at com.atlassian.plugin.loaders.ScanningPluginLoader.loadAllPlugins(ScanningPluginLoader.java:89)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] at com.atlassian.plugin.loaders.PermissionCheckingPluginLoader.loadAllPlugins(PermissionCheckingPluginLoader.java:24)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] at com.atlassian.plugin.manager.DefaultPluginManager.init(DefaultPluginManager.java:217)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] at com.atlassian.jira.plugin.JiraPluginManager.start(JiraPluginManager.java:83)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] at com.atlassian.jira.ComponentManager$PluginSystem.start(ComponentManager.java:722)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] at com.atlassian.jira.ComponentManager.quickStart(ComponentManager.java:225)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] at com.atlassian.jira.ComponentManager.start(ComponentManager.java:199)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] at com.atlassian.jira.upgrade.PluginSystemLauncher.start(PluginSystemLauncher.java:24)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] at com.atlassian.jira.startup.DefaultJiraLauncher$3.run(DefaultJiraLauncher.java:130)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] at com.atlassian.jira.config.database.DatabaseConfigurationManagerImpl.doNowOrEnqueue(DatabaseConfigurationManagerImpl.java:317)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] at com.atlassian.jira.config.database.DatabaseConfigurationManagerImpl.doNowOrWhenDatabaseActivated(DatabaseConfigurationManagerImpl.java:211)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] at com.atlassian.jira.startup.DefaultJiraLauncher.postDbLaunch(DefaultJiraLauncher.java:118)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] at com.atlassian.jira.startup.DefaultJiraLauncher.access$100(DefaultJiraLauncher.java:32)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] at com.atlassian.jira.startup.DefaultJiraLauncher$1.run(DefaultJiraLauncher.java:81)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] at com.atlassian.jira.util.devspeed.JiraDevSpeedTimer.run(JiraDevSpeedTimer.java:34)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] at com.atlassian.jira.startup.DefaultJiraLauncher.start(DefaultJiraLauncher.java:76)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] at com.atlassian.jira.startup.LauncherContextListener.contextInitialized(LauncherContextListener.java:54)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4973)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5467)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:632)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1073)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1857)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 1):

The key error would appear to be this:

```
com.atlassian.plugin.osgi.factory.transform.PluginTransformationException: Unable to add files to plugin jar
```

This usually indicates some sort of disk-related error, so the likely causes are either:

- you are out of disk space or disk quota on the filesystem holding your $JIRA_DATA directory, or
- there is some sort of permission problem and the OS user account that JIRA runs under is unable to modify the necessary files within your $JIRA_DATA directory.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error because the name of my jar file was too long.